# Manual Vaadin Project Deploy on Raspbian

Tags: maven, vaadin, raspbian

For a project I want to do a performance comparison of different web-frameworks on a raspberry pi. Thats why I want to do only a manual deploy to mess around with it a bit.

I created a Vaadin project using maven and exported it as application.war file. I downloaded the tomcat-7 server and unzipped it. After that I gave the .sh files in the folder executable permission. Then I copied .war file in the webapps folder of tomcat. Finally I started tomcat by running `sh startup.sh`.
But when I try to open the page on my dev machine under ip:8080/application I only receive a timeout.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Did you install java in your RPI? Is tomcat up and running on your RPI?  Are there any error in the tomcat logs?

Comment: Yes I installed Thema complete not just Lite image. Jdk7 and 8 are include. When running the Tomcat Server I do not get any errors.

Comment: But can you see your app being deployed in the tomcat logs? Is tomcat running after you attempt to start it? Is port 8080 open by tomcat? Also can you post your UI class and servlet configuration?

Comment: @Morfic Indeed there seems to be a problem with the war file. This is what I found in the catalina logs: https://pastebin.com/DFJ6SVV3 . I have no idea why - it's the basic vaadin example app, which runs just perfectly on my dev machine.

Comment: Perhaps the file was corrupted during upload. If you copy it locally and unzip it, or try unzipping it on the machine, does it work? Alternatively, which OS user is the owner of the war and under what user is tomcat running (although in this case I'd expect a different exception)?

Comment: I tried to upload it using the management console on the tomcat starting page - strangely enough that worked. I hope that if we are deciding on using tomcat auto deploy works from the get go.

Comment: Can you check the permission for the war file from the manual deployment. Maybe tomcat isn't allowed to read it.

Comment: where can i find that?

Comment: i assume you are on linux so "ls -l yourTomcatPath/webapps" and the output is something like this: -rw-r--r-- 1 user user ...

Comment: Can you deploy the same war to some other tomcat or similar instance?